# how can i put data from my database or website to my mobile application (im working with HTML5 and ionic)?

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

i want to develope ionic / HTML5 mobile application , i have data on my server and i want  to import theme to put it in my mobile application when user search for something

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the same thing that you do in a normal html5 application...

```js
angular  
  .module('test', [])
  .service('DataLayerService', function($q, $http) {
      var self = this;
  
      self.loadData = function() {
        var configs = { cache: false };
        
        configs.params = {};
        
        return $http
          .get('http://myapp.com/api/v1/datalayer/...', configs)
          .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
          });
      };
  });
```

Comment: do you know a youtube tutorial for this

Comment: No, it's just a snippet that I wrote today, you probably need for http://www.apress.com/9781430264484 this book.